# Modx getresources foreach

Tags: foreach, modx

I have this snippet :

```
<?php
$list = $modx->runSnippet('getResources', array(
'parents'=>'16',
'depth'=>'1',
'includeContent'=>'1',
'limit'=>'1'
));

$output = explode(',', $list);
//print_r($list);

foreach($output as $i) {
  //echo $i;
  foreach($i as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.' : '.$value.'<br />';
  }
}
```

With print_r I can see the array ;-)

But using the foreach loop... nothing print !

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be that you are calling 'explode' on an array when it should be taking a string.

Not sure exactly what your $list array looks like, but perhaps try this instead:

```
foreach ($list as $i) {
  foreach ($i as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.' : '.$value.'<br />';
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
Have tested this and $list is not an array but a pre-formatted string meant for debugging:

```
<pre>Array
    (
    [tpl] => 
    [tplOdd] => 
    [tplFirst] => 
...
</pre>
```

I'm not sure exactly what you want to achieve, but it's usually better to use the **tpl** parameter to format results using a Chunk.

getResources is designed for listing Resources for front end display and is not generally used to retrieve raw data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I already tried and it does not work

Comment: Thanks. I understand now why I cannot loop with foreach ;-) In fact I want to format the result of the GetResources with a Snippet and save it in a .txt file

Comment: No problem :) Just set up your chunk to format your data how you want it and you can then manipulate it in the snippet. It will be output as a string though, just bear that in mind.

If you found my answer helpful, please mark it as 'accepted'. Thanks.

Comment: Can you help me with a small example.
What I need to do is to use 
`$list = $modx->runSnippet('getResources', array(
'parents'=>'16',
'depth'=>'1',
'includeContent'=>'1'
));`

and in my Snippet to use **feedcreator.class.php** to save the feed as test.rss

Comment: Hey Chris, I think you are making things difficult for yourself - there's a good tute on how to do this without any custom coding required: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/getResources.Building+a+RSS+feed